# The method WhiteRectangleDetector is undefined for the type main

Tags: java, barcode, zxing

I'm trying to use the WhiteRectangleDetector() function with the zxing library with Java (Eclipse). I added the core-3.3.0.jar and javase-3.3.0.jar as User-Library.

```
LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(barCodeBufferedImage);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
result = reader.decode(bitmap);
ResultPoint[] scannedCoord = result.getResultPoints();

System.out.println("ResultPoint 1: " + scannedCoord[0]); 
System.out.println("ResultPoint 2: " + scannedCoord[1]);

System.out.println("\n Barcode text is " + result.getText() + "\n");

System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------");

BitMatrix bitMatrix = bitmap.getBlackMatrix();
System.out.println(bitMatrix.getTopLeftOnBit());
System.out.println(bitMatrix.getBottomRightOnBit());

ResultPoint[] wrpts = WhiteRectangleDetector(bitMatrix);
```

I get this error message: The method WhiteRectangleDetector(BitMatrix) is undefined for the type main!

Comment: But you didn't fix your imports,huh?

Comment: Your imports may be missing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WhiteRectangleDetector](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/common/detector/WhiteRectangleDetector.html) is a class, not method. To use it you need to create an instance of it with a `new` call:

```
WhiteRectangleDetector detector = new WhiteRectangleDetector(bitMatrix);
//now you can call methods
ResultPoint[] wrpts = detector.detect();
```

Comment: You saved my Day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rajx82 You're welcome! Don't forget [to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)